# Errors in Graphite server log

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I am running 1 carbon-relay instance (Graphite-server) and 4 carbon cache instances running on same host and 4 different ports (2014,2016,2018,2020). My Graphite server log is full of below messages for each of the carbon cache instances. Below is one example for port 2020

12/07/2023 05:59:58 :: [clients] CarbonClientProtocol(127.0.0.1:2020:04)::connectionMade
12/07/2023 05:59:58 :: [clients] CarbonClientFactory(127.0.0.1:2020:04)::connectionMade (CarbonClientProtocol(127.0.0.1:2020:04))
12/07/2023 05:59:58 :: [clients] Destination is up: 127.0.0.1:2020:04
12/07/2023 05:59:59 :: [clients] CarbonClientProtocol(127.0.0.1:2020:04)::connectionLost Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.
12/07/2023 05:59:59 :: [console] <twisted.internet.tcp.Connector instance at 0x7f9576756a20 disconnected IPv4Address(type='TCP', host='127.0.0.1', port=2020)> will retry in 2 seconds
12/07/2023 05:59:59 :: [clients] CarbonClientFactory(127.0.0.1:2020:04)::clientConnectionLost (127.0.0.1:2020) Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.
12/07/2023 05:59:59 :: [clients] Destination is down: 127.0.0.1:2020:04 (1/5)
12/07/2023 05:59:59 :: [console] Stopping factory CarbonClientFactory(127.0.0.1:2020:04)

I am getting metrics in Graphite/Grafana but this looks like something is wrong.

Could you help ?

Thanks

Looked at my settings and they look correct to me. Also I am getting metrics published in Graphite dashboard